# Unable to access MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use MySQL with my first website, and using [biz.nf](http://www.biz.nf/) to host it.

The website control panel gives me the following info for the MySQL database I have created, which I have stored in a login.php file

```
<?php 
$db_hostname =  (hostname);
$db_database =  (db name);
$db_username = (username);
$db_password = '********'; //not showing here
$db_port = '3306';
?>
```

I then try and access it with the following code:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_port, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
?>
```

Which doesn't work, giving me the following error.

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user '3306'@'83.125.22.189' (using password: YES) in /srv/disk12/1570263/www/erfbattle.co.nf/index.html on line 18
Unable to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user '3306'@'83.125.22.189' (using password: YES)
```

I tried doing a port check on fdb4.biz.nf with port number 3306, and found that the port was closed. I'm kind of new to this, and trying to figure out what could be wrong here.

Comment: Perhaps you should contact the database host to ensure the address and credentials are correct.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: is this error from your local development machine or from the hosted site?most mysql servers won't allow connection from outside.

Answer (score 5):

You have put your parameters in the wrong order. As you'll notice in your error, the port is being passed as the username. You should change the order of your parameters.

That being said, you shouldn't use `mysql_` functions, as mentioned in the comments above. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement

```
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_port, $db_username, $db_password);
```

should be

```
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname.":".$db_port, $db_username, $db_password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Port 3306 is the default port for MySql. Try the hostname with Localhost. And in the control panel assign the Username to the database. In Cpanel there will be a option to do this.